# Should we tell browsersync to reload specific resource types?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, browser-sync

I have created a command line [utility for css editing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli) that uses browsersync for live reload.

The `serve` command watches for changes to specific resource types (Javascript, CSS,and HTML) and triggers browsersync reloads.  My question is suppose the developer edits a CSS file.  Should we tell browersync to only reload CSS resources like this:

```
bs.reload("*.css");
```

Or do we tell it to reload html, which in turn reloads css...hopefully:

```
bs.reload("*.html");
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the live reload of specific resource types (I.e. `*.css` when css changes), and is working fine, so it seems the answer is to target specific resource types during live reload.